# How to know if my parameter is a char or a char* with varargs

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a function who takes a two parameters, the fist one is always a char* the second one can be a char or a char*

then, this is what i want to do

```
void   my_function(char  *arg1, XXXX arg2)
{
 if (XXXX == char)
        //convert arg2 in char*
  do_something_else(arg2);
}
```

the problem is, i dont know how i can get the type of arg2

Comment: It's simple: you can't. You need to specify that information in a different way, explicitly.

Comment: so i have to do 2 functions, one who takes a char, and one who take a char* ? i read something about varargs bt i dont know if it's apropriate

Comment: No, you can do it in one function, e. g. with an extra parameter that tells the type of the argument.

Comment: Standard C functions do it by using the type name as a suffix.  See for example the fget family:  `fgets`, `fgetc`, `fgetws`, `fgetwc`.  Varargs are not appropriate to use in your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a struct containing your types with an additional member that selects the chosen type.

```
struct my
{
    char* s ;
    char c ;
    int type ;
}
```

And then use a check that does the right thing:

```
if( m.type == 1 )
{
   m.s = ... //do something with char*
}
else if( m.type == 2 )
{
   m.c = ... //do something with char
}
```

If you insist on using a variable arguments function, then use the approach used by printf(). The first argument contains number and types of every passed optional arguments.